# div элементы в одну строку

Tags: html, css

Как расположить div элементы в одну строку?

```
.div1 { display: inline; }

<div class="div1">
       <img .... >
    </div>
    <div class="div1">
       <img .... >
    </div>
    <div class="div1">
       <img .... >
    </div>
```

Картинки выстраиваются в ряд. Но как быть, если например, под картиной нужно сделать описание?

```
.div1 { display: inline; }
<div class="div1">
   <img .... >
   <div class="about"> image1 </div>
</div>
<div class="div1">
   <img .... >
   <div class="about"> image2 </div>
</div>
<div class="div1">
   <img .... >
   <div class="about"> image3 </div>
</div>
```

То элементы div1 снова начинаются с новой строки.
как быть?

Comment: <br /> Так не пойдет?)) Ну или таблицей попробовать.

Comment: <br/> тоже не то, элементы выстраиваются в колонку. Хотелось бы решить это без таблиц))

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Просто

```
.div1 {display:inline-block;}
```

А вот так можно уменьшить количество кода:

```
.about {
 display:inline-block;
}

.about img {
 display:block;
}

<div id="images">

   <div class="about">
   <img src="pic.png">
   image1
   </div>

   <div class="about">
   <img src="pic.png">
   image2
   </div>

   <div class="about">
   <img src="pic.png">
   image3
   </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Я советую использовать  flex, вот пример кода:

### HTML file:

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="con1"></div>
    <div id="con2"></div>
    <div id="con3"></div>
</div>
```

### CSS file:

```css
.container{

    display: flex;

    flex-direction: row;

    justify-content: flex-start;

    border: 5px solid black;

    padding: 20px;
}

#con1{
    width: 150px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    background-color: green;
    height: 150px;
    border-right: 0px;
}

#con2{
    width: 100%;
    border: 2px solid black;
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 300px;
}
#con3{
    width: 150px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-left: 0px;
    background-color: green;
    height: 150px;
}
```

[Советую почитать](http://css.yoksel.ru/flexbox/)

Answer (score 2):

Используй `display: inline-block` или `float: left` на селектор `.div1`
[Подробнее про выравнивание элементов](http://web-sprints.ru/css-elementyi-v-stroku/).

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.

Answer (score 1):

Все дело в том, что внутри - блочный элемент. Попробуйте так:

```
<span>
    <div>123</div>
</span>
<span>
    <div>123</div>
</span>
<span>
    <div>123</div>
</span>
```

SPAN - inline элемент, но DIV - блочный. Результат - все в столбик.

Уберите везде DIV - получите результат в строку.

Для того, чтобы получить то, что хотите - можно указать не display: inline, а display: inline-block, либо делать через таблицы (не в тегах, а в стилях - например, display: table)