# Как расположить два видео в одну строку

Tags: html

Помогите пожалуйста! 
Мне нужно что бы 2 видео были в линию

```
<div class="brd">
  <video width="400" height="300" controls="controls">
    <source src="ВИДЕО" >
  </video>
</div>
```

Это 1 видео, а мне нужно что бы было второе видео правее. Я не знаю, как правильно это разместить в коде. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [div элементы в одну строку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/198307/div-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d1%8b-%d0%b2-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d1%83-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%83)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Помещаете второе видео в аналогичный div с классом .brd и задаёте эту классу стиль display: inline-block;

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: @sanjar123, обращайтесь :)

Comment: На такие базовые вопросы тебе Гугл быстрее ответит. Учись пользоваться. https://www.google.ru/search?q=Css+%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B+%D0%B2+%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4&gws_rd=cr&dcr=1&ei=mWJPWvf5MMilsAG1m4zQBg

Answer (score 0):

Каждое видео в отдельный  если не поможет, то задай этим дивам клас со свойством display: inline-block;

Comment: И будут они друг под другом.

Comment: потому что не block, а inline-block :))